# Suitable checksum for uniquely identifying a series of numbers in Postgres 9 and Java

Tags: java, postgresql, checksum

Given a series of numbers (generally less than 20 numbers with values between 100 & 1000 but not necessarily)

e.g
100, 343, 234, 123, 456, 345, 80, 99, 100

what is a good checksum  such as to minimize the risk of a different series of different numbers, (different order is an important as different numbers) giving the same checksum.

Looking for a checksum that is available in PostgreSQL 9 and Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest converting to a delimited string and then use MD5() in Postgres and java.security.MessageDigest / getInstance("MD5") in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the array as simplest solution here:

```
db=# select '{2,4,5}'::int[] = '{2,4,5}'::int[];
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

db=# select '{2,4,5}'::int[] = '{2,5,4}'::int[];
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

While I don't think you need checksum here as you can operate integer arrays directly as shown above - array is a value. But in case you need a hash, you can surely cast it to text and use md5:

```
db=# select md5('{2,4,5}'::int[]::text) = md5('{2,5,4}'::int[]::text);
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

But again. If I understand correctly, you want hash so you could compare series. Postgres allows you doing it without hashing - with native data type `integer[]` - array of integers, obviously the order in array matters...

Comment: but wheres the checksum, the calling app needs to pass a value that can be used to  lookup the row with this series

Comment: Sorry my question was incomplete, the idea of the hash is that the user will create a hash of their data (not in database) and then call a webservice using that looks to find matching data in database using the hash as a key. i.e i need a value that can be easily transferred over a webservice